# Multi direction gravity 2D Platform Game - trigonometry issue

Tags: 2d, game-physics, platform, gravity

So, like the title said, I'm making a 2D platform game with multi direction physics, but my lack of trigonometry skills are killing me.

When my character hits something, it returns a Vector2 hitPoint.

If this was a one-way gravity platform game, I would do the following:

```
// considering the player's origin point in the middle
public void HitGround(Vector2 hitPoint)
{
   this.position.y = hitPoint.y + height /2;
}
```

But since this have multi gravity physics, this simple method can't be done. So I've worked with relative positions, suppose the gravity is (-3, -3), the player would fall southwest.

```
// considering the player's origin point in the middle
public void HitGround(Vector2 hitPoint)
{
    this.position = hitPoint + GetRelativeYPos(height / 2);
}

// returns the relative Y position based on its rotation
public Vector2 GetRelativeYPos(float offset)
{
    // rotation is a Quaternion
    return this.rotation * new Vector2(0, 1) * offset;
}
```

So far, so good. It works perfectly!!! But wait... this is only working when the CENTER of the player hits the ground. In fact, the player has 3 raycasts when he is falling. If the center raycast hits the ground, the code WORKS in EVERY direction he falls.

But when the EDGE RAYCASTS hits the ground. The Player tilts to the center, because the code do not allow him to move right. Now, my last code idea was born:

```
public void HitGround(Vector2 hitPoint, Vector2 raycastOrigin)
{
    // Considering that the raycastOrigin is in the same "relative X" as the player's origin

    float signedDistance = SignedDistance(hitPoint, raycastOrigin);

    this.position = hitPoint + GetRelativeYPos(height / 2) + GetRelativeXPos(signedDistance);
}

// returns the relative Y position based on its rotation
public Vector2 GetRelativeYPos(float offset)
{
    return this.rotation * new Vector2(0, 1) * offset;
}

// returns the relative X position based on its rotation
public Vector2 GetRelativeXPos(float offset)
{
    return this.rotation * new Vector2(1, 0) * offset;
}

public float SignedDistance(Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2)
{
    float distance = Distance(p1, p2);
    float angle = Atan2(p2.y, p2.x) + Atan2(p1.y, p1.x);

    // Returns the magnitude AND direction of the vector
    return distance * Sign(angle);
}
```

And there you go!

When the code doesn't work, its just because of the sign of the angle, that, for some reason, it's being calculated wrong, When the angle has to be positive, it returns negative, and vice versa, but it only returns the wrong value when the "player's relative north position" is below 0.

For example:

if the player is falling down, when the Y position is higher than 0, it works, when it is lower, it doesn't.

If the player is falling up, when the Y position is lower than 0, it works, when it is higher, it doesn't.

If the player is falling right, when the X position is lower than 0, it works, when it is 
higher, it doesn't.

If the player is falling left, when the X position is greater than 0, it works, when it is lower, it doesn't.

Just one more:

If the player is falling southeast, when the Y position is higher than 0 AND the X position is lower than 0, it works, otherwise, it doesn't

The following method is the responsible for calculating the "signed distance" of two points. I mean, the magnitude of the resulting vector and its direction

`public float SignedDistance(Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2)
    {
        float distance = Distance(p1, p2);`

```
    // THIS LINE HERE!!!
    float angle = Atan2(p2.y, p2.x) + Atan2(p1.y, p1.x);

    return distance * Sign(angle);
}
```

There is something wrong with that line that I CAN'T FIGURE IT OUT. Is there someone kind enough to answer this question?

I hope I was clear. Bye

Comment: It's impressive when we ask a question and minutes later the answer pops up. So, as soon the raycast is created, I register the raycast distance relative to the center in a custom Class HitData, which contains the RaycastHit AND the distance..

When some edge raycast hits the ground, it calls the relativeDistance of the HitData, and updates its x position accordingly.


The solution was simpler, lighter and faster. Thanks for this community for existing, if it didn't, I wouldn't have written my problem down and probably would still be banging my head against the wall.

Bye. Sorry to bother.